# Inverse mellin transform of $\Gamma^3(s)$

Tags: complex-analysis, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

Is the inverse mellin transform of $\Gamma^3(s)$ known? Mathematica tells that inverse mellin transform of $\Gamma^2(s)$ is $2 K_0(2\sqrt{x})$ where $K_0(x)$ is the bessel function. I would like to know if inverse mellin transform of $\Gamma^3(s)$ exists in terms of special functions other that Meiger $G$ function.

Comment: Mathematica `13.0` says: $$\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\Gamma (s)^3\right](x)=G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$ where $G$ is MeijerG function. And: $$\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\Gamma (s)^4\right](x)=G_{0,4}^{4,0}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

Comment: yeah I too got the same output, can we simplify Meiger G further? Like sometimes Meiger G function reduces to Bessel functions.

Comment: I do not think than we can simplify Meiger G further

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/03/01/05/01/